# Is FCM messaging working well for unpublished app?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

that's not the first time I'm wondering how GCM/FCM works when the application is in background.

And now I'm modifying my application I realize that it doesn't receive `data` messages when the application is in background whereas the same message is well received by application in foreground.

if I install the published one from Google Play, it's working well in all cases.

If I get the published app's project back and rebuild it, FCM messages are not received when the app is in background. That's a nightmare.

So I'm wondering if FCM is fully working for unpublished application !?!

My message is (tested from Advanced Rest Client):

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "feWpp3aQ8sQ:A...dclQ1hSttsf",
    "feDmzDRi-gw:A...O9ur7oXi",
    "f7dbqek_rPo:APA91bEu...a1rSje0bNmPq8"
  ],
  "data": {
    "id": 19,
    "title": "Title test",
    "msg": "Text of the test",
    "code": 2,
    "infosUrl": "www.myexample.com",
    "eventLocation": "Nowhere",
    "latitude": 47.90022515672,
    "longitude": 15.0196307059377,
    "startDate": "2016/05/14 20:00",
    "endDate": "2016/05/14 22:00",
    "publishEndDate": "",
    "image": ""
  },
  "delay_while_idle": false,
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.my.example"
  android:installLocation="auto"
  android:versionCode="52"
  android:versionName="@string/app_version">

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

      <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
          android:label="@string/app_name">

          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>

          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
          </intent-filter>

      </activity>

      <activity
          android:name=".PreferencesActivity"
          android:label="@string/label_preferenceScreen"/>

      <activity
          android:name=".FragmentPreferences"
          android:label="@string/label_preferenceScreen"/>

      <service android:name=".MyFcmListenerService">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>

      <service
          android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>

      <service
          android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
          android:exported="false" />

  </application>
```

My gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
  compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.2@aar'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the Listener:

```
public class MyFcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage fcmMessage) {

        Map data = fcmMessage.getData();

        int code = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("code"));

        switch (code) {
          case 1: // Event
              ....
              break;


          default:
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

Did you experience such strange problem??

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether it is published/unpublished app to receive a notification/message.What fcm server need s is a valid registration id.
Your MyFcmListenerService with com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT action  is responsible for receiving messages.That means you have intentionally registered that service to notify you/your app whenever that particular action occurs because of this whenever your app is in background also your app will get notification/message.
MyInstanceIDListenerService is responsible to receive the registration id for your app.
There is no problem in receiving messages with GCM/FCM whether your app is foreground/background.

Comment: The message is sucessfully sent to the device; I just notice that even with a previously running project (running app from Google Play), background receive doesn't work anymore once the project is rebuilt... It's what I cannot understand right now. and it's not specific to some device.